# Showing attributes/labels from KML in Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps, kml, angularjs

I have converted my cover, it is said (from archived .shp to .kml) in QGIS and this is the way it is read in angular:

```
this.kmlLayerc1= new google.maps.KmlLayer({ 
    url: 'http://direccion/carpeta/nombre.kml',
    map: this.map
});
```

But when I look at it in the map, it does not show with the attributes as in QGIS, and the same thing happens with google earth that they dont show.

This is my archived .shp, I would like to show it the same way as you can see in google maps or google earth.

[image]

This is a link to the same problem
https://support.esri.com/es/technical-article/000012154

only that I already tried it but I was not succesful

Anyone have a solution or suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

According to the same problem you linked to,

> Google Earth only displays labels for point features (placemarks). To
>   display labels for line or polygon features in Google Earth, midpoints
>   or centroids for those feature classes must be created as a point
>   layer